# Is there a Public Link Sharing list?

Tags: lightning, soql, api, files, public-link-sharing

New to Salesforce administration, and just found out that there is an option to create a public link for files.

Is there a way to see all public links created in the instance I manage just like in Google drive? Even if it's only via API / SOQL that works for me.
Also, is there a way to have an expiration date for the links? I would really like to limit my users on this.

Thanks!

(I already searched the Salesforce documentation, this subreddit, and Salesforce Stack Exchange)

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XnpvQAC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same question and just found the answer. This blog post by forcepanda really helped - https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2021/05/04/generating-public-url-for-salesforce-files/

You need to query the ContentDistribution table. This will provide all the public links and related metadata.